# svgalib : cant see anything

Tags: linux, graphics, vga

I had compiled some examples from svgalib, the console show : 

`Using EGA driver
svglib 1.4.3`

Nothing more, its like its drawing somewhere but I cannot see it.
This could be a ver very noob question about svgalib, but also a configuration problem.

Also I check the virtual console that it says is drawing (if I run from X), running from console just stays there. I also put sleep in the code

example code :

```
 
include stdlib.h
include vga.h
```

int main(void)
{
   vga_init();
   vga_setmode(G320x200x256);
   vga_setcolor(4);
   vga_drawpixel(10, 10);

sleep(5);
   vga_setmode(TEXT);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

compile with
gcc -o tut tut.c -lvga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do you have other [SVGAlib](http://www.svgalib.org/) applications working on your system? Such `svgatest`, which may be in a separate distribution package (*svgalib-bin* or similar).

Have you configured svgalib for your system? Common locate of the config file is `/etc/vga/libvga.config` and read `man svgalib` should give you more details.

I suspect that once you have SVGAlib working in general, the tutorial example program will work.

Answer (score -2):

Install by software manager all svgalibrary.

Set the resolution at yours graphics screen

es : G1024x768x256

set color pixel white = 15

my linux mint (mate) 17.1 on hard disk work fine.

good luck !